# Operators Precedence in C/C++

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Could you help me explain this result:

```
int b = 5, i = 0;
i = ++b + ++b + b++;
```

The actual result is 21 (run program)
In my opinion, the order of calculation is:
`b++` (posfix): return 5 and b = 6
the first `++b`: return 7 and b = 7
the second `++b`: return 8 and b = 8
So the resuld should be: i = 7 + 8 + 5 = 20.
What wrong with my calculation ? anyone can help.

Comment: This is not a matter of operator precendence. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: @RHertel, can you explain more detail ?

Comment: @TrongHoangbao [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/Tsc7We3Yx).  The output is 20.  What is the reason for the output being different?  See the duplicate link, and it will explain what undefined behavior is.  Also, *read the compiler warnings*.  If the output were 0, or 20, or 21, or 200, the compiler would be "correct".